# How to play content in ar after detection of marker without marker all the time(one time detection and then play)

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality, aframe, web-ar

I started some of the examples in web ar, I found that all example works on nft or marker. I want to make something like it should not always depend upon marker or nft. As soon as marker is detected I should be able to play the content in AR without the need of marker anymore.

Sorry, my English sucks.
Waiting for help. Thanks

Comment: arjs works with markers and nft. There is also [WebXR AR](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/use-new-augmented-reality-features-with-just-a-few-lines-of-code-with-webxr-and-aframe-c6f3f5789345), which doesn't need markers or nft. If you prefer arjs, the video could pop up where the marker was first detected and stay there (screen wise, not 'world position' wise)

Comment: Yes, I want to make the video pop up where the marker was first detected and stay there, any help or code will be appreciated.(means when the marker is detected, I can move my camera anywhere but still I can play video irrespective of marker)

Comment: I have experienced lot of shakes while playing video or 3D model through marker, I guess this will fix that shaking issue and no need of holding camera in front of marker all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the element **on-screen** where the marker was detected.

Just wait until the marker is detected, and copy its position, rotation and scale to the entity with the content. A component doing this could look like this:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('video-logic', {
    init: function () {
        const marker = document.querySelector("a-marker");

        marker.addEventListener("markerFound", evt => {
          // you can wait a while so the content won't appear somewhere on the border
          setTimeout(evt => {
            this.el.setAttribute("position", marker.getAttribute("position");
            this.el.setAttribute("rotation", marker.getAttribute("rotation");
          }, 500)
        })
    }
});

// The content is separate from the marker
//<a-box material="src: #video;" video-logic></a-box>
//<a-marker smooth="true" preset="hiro"></a-marker>
```

Something like I did [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/arjs/stay-on-screen.html)

Comment: Thanks for a solution but Will it work for nft (image tracking) also?

Comment: Yup. Although i think that nft tracking has scaling issues, so It won't be as precise as markers. Same example but with [nft here](https://192.168.0.129:8080/webzamples/arjs/stay-on-screen-image.html)

Comment: Sir, I can't see video and a model, but can here a audio when the nft is detected from your example.

Comment: @RamyaYadav do you have your work [glitch](https://glitch.com/) or somewhere on github? Or at least not a full project but a sample with the NFT detection

Comment: I have tried to implement your stay-on-screen script in my work, but I couldn't able to do it.         My work: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ghost-of                                         live site :  https://ghost-of.glitch.me                  Use this image: https://cdn.glitch.com/7fcfdaac-9d7f-4d8f-bad0-91ab3f0abc31%2Fghost.jpg?v=1633335957522

Comment: I have posted my question in public, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69434247/how-to-make-content-model-video-stay-on-screen-using-nft-in-web-ar